Multiple dynamic Swiper JS slides on same page
Let's say I have a custom CMS which allows me to add multiple slides on a page and each slide will have different options (slides to show at a time, slides to scroll, breakpoints, etc)
To my knowledge Swiper JS does not support data attributes in the slider HTML. It is something that needs to be implemented manually?
Im currently generating multiple slides on a page like this:
<div class="swiper" data-swiper='{"slidesPerView":3,"slidesPerGroup":3,"speed":300}}'>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
       <div class="swiper-slide">...</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">...</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="swiper" data-swiper='{"slidesPerView":1,"slidesPerGroup":1,"speed":800}}'>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
       <div class="swiper-slide">...</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">...</div>
       <div class="swiper-slide">...</div>
    </div>
</div>

Then I use custom JS:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper');

  sliders.forEach(slider => {
    const swiperOptions = JSON.parse(slider.getAttribute('data-swiper'));

    // Initialize Swiper instance
    new Swiper(slider, {
      ...swiperOptions,

This works. However is there a better more official way to handle multiple dynamic slides?

better depends on you.  If you want other devs to be able to easily create new sliders by just adding html and not modifying js, this is a good way.
